# RecyclerView footer is not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, footer

I have tried to show footer in RecyclerView infinte scrolling but the footer is sometimes shown so fast sometimes it doesnt show at all.Is there problem in the given code??

```
 public class CustomRecyclerViewScrollListener extends    RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    int visibleCount = 0;
    int totalItemCount = 0;
    int pastVisibleItems = 0;
    int lastVisibleItem=0;

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleCount = llm.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = llm.getItemCount();
        pastVisibleItems = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        lastVisibleItem=llm.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        if (!isLoading && !dataFinished && list.size() % 10 == 0) {
            if ((visibleCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    isLoading = true;
                    loadMore();
                    adapter.showViewHolderFooter();                   

                 }
            }
        } else {             
               adapter.hideViewHolderFooter();               

        }
    }
```

Comment: You might want to start with showing footer before `loadMore`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount,totalItemCount,pastVisiblesItems;
private boolean loading = true;

    reyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                    if (dy > 0) //check for scroll down
                    {
                        visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                        totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                        pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                        if (loading) {
                            if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                                loading = false;
                                expandapleInt++;

                              //Your operation
                        }
                         }
                    }
                }
            });
```

In my code for every operation set `loading = true;` in your code set `isLoading`  to false before every load starts